# The alt="" attribute is empty

Tags: images

My WordPress installation creates empty `alt` attributes inside images. I also installed the plugin *SEO Friendly Images* but it did not change anything.

```
<img
class="highmage" src="http://kringelhauser.lukaseichler.de/wp-content/themes/Reporter/timthumb.php?src=http://kringelhauser.lukaseichler.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/redtube-abmahnung.jpg&amp;h=100&amp;w=310&amp;zc=1" alt="" />
```

Comment: Images _where_, in post content? Do you see `alt` in editor but not live on site?

Comment: The alt text and descriptions are set in the editor but they are not showing on the site.

Comment: Does it still happen with plugins disabled and default theme?

Comment: @Rarst Disabling every plugin and changing to the default theme did not change anything.

Comment: Could you please add to the question short example of markup demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @Rarst added a orgninal img Tag from the WordPress Site.

Comment: But the `alt` attribute **is** actually empty in your example?

Comment: @Rarst Yes my description was not very accurate, I updated the question.

Comment: @Rarst sup? ...